# How to remove a specific element from XML, using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<batch xmlns="http://www.concursolutions.com/api/user/2011/02" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <UserProfile>
    <EmpId>123456</EmpId>
    <NewEmployeeID>
    </NewEmployeeID>
  </UserProfile>
</batch>
```

and I need to transform this XML to this shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<batch xmlns="http://www.concursolutions.com/api/user/2011/02" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <UserProfile>
    <EmpId>123456</EmpId>
  </UserProfile>
</batch>
```

This is the XSLT I tried but it didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml"
              indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NewEmployeeID"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can you please help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NewEmployeeID` is in the default namespace which uri is `"http://www.concursolutions.com/api/user/2011/02"`. You need to use prefix that mapped to the default namespace uri to match that element :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet .......
       xmlns:d="http://www.concursolutions.com/api/user/2011/02">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  .........
  <xsl:template match="d:NewEmployeeID"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: when I typed "<xsl:template match="d:NewEmployeeID"/>" , I got an error "Prefix 'd' is not defined".It didn't work

Comment: Notice how the prefix "d" is defined at xsl:stylesheet element in the snippet above

Comment: ok, my bad. I added "d" defined at xsl:stylesheet element. <NewEmployeeID> element totally gone but left a space like                                                                                                      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<batch xmlns="http://www.concursolutions.com/api/user/2011/02" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <UserProfile>
    <EmpId>123456</EmpId>
 ......SPACE HERE ......
  </UserProfile>
</batch>      Is there anyway to get rid of this 1 line empty space in the XML?

Comment: @ms_jordan use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` as in the updated snippet

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a star. It worked. I want to upvote your solution but I get validation message that I don't have enough reputation points to vote anything. You solution is the Answer! Thank you so much again.

Comment: @ms_jordan No problem, [accepting answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (when appropriate, off course) will help you to get upvoting privilege